# Unable to get zoom effect with Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer library

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode7

I am working on integrating Apple's [ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) library in one of my App. I have tried with their sample code also but it didn't allow me to zoom (Tested on device as well as on simulator). I have gone through FAQ and other sections but could not found any solution for the same. However PDF viewing works fine.

I am using Xcode 7.2 and testing on iPad in landscape mode. Does this library really support zooming ? Can anybody please tell me how can I enable zoom in it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **DataViewController.m** file of library code in viewWillAppear is there for that

// Disable zooming if our pages are currently shown in landscape

```
if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
{
    [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
else
{
    [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

Setting NO to Yes here will enable zoom in landscape mode. But the zooming isn't handled well as that in portrait mode..

Comment: I want to zoom pages in landscape for that I have enabled user interaction but getting unexpected result. Instead of zoom in out both pages become moveable. What should I do to achieve zoom in out feature in landscape mode.

Comment: @AhadKhan That's the limitation of this library. As I written in my answer "Setting NO to Yes here will enable zoom in landscape mode. But the zooming isn't handled well as that portrait mode.."